# Is it technically correct to say I have "one exam" if I actually have four exams?

Tags: numbers, semantics

If a college student asks one of his fellow students the question:

> Do you have one exam?

and the student replies:

> Yes, I have one exam.

when he actually has four exams, is the answer technically false?

Comment: Related: ['A / One / At least one student entered the room.' Are these the same? (truth-conditionally)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292760/a-one-at-least-one-student-entered-the-room-are-these-the-same-truth-co)

Comment: 'Technically' is ill-defined (in fact very polysemous).

Comment: "Sally, did you eat any cookies from that platter I have for the guests?"  "I didn't eat one!"  "But there's only one left" "That's the one I didn't eat."

Comment: @Hot Licks We could do with fewer belly laughs here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - The laughs aren't the problem.  I'm guessing we could do with fewer bellies.

Comment: @Hot Licks These unwarranted assumptions are unacceptable. Especially when they're true. I blame my wife. She's a wonderful cook.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - My wife just baked a bunch of chocolate chip cookies.  Come over and have a few!

Answer (score -1):

Technically, if you have four exams then you also have one exam. The answer is not technically false.

But the question is unnatural.

A natural question would be:

```
Do you have just one exam?
```

And a more natural answer would be:

```
Yes, just one.
```

But this time, because the word *just* is used, the student is lying if he or she has four exams! *Just one* means not more and not less than one.

[Definition of *Just*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/just):

```
exactly or precisely
```