# Does "two of whom" imply a minimum of two, or exactly two?

Tags: phrases

This is from rules of FIFA:

> "The final list of the 14 players (two of whom shall be goalkeepers) selected to participate in the final competition shall be submitted to the FIFA general secretariat ...

The phrase in question is **"two of whom shall be goalkeepers"**. What does it mean exactly? Two possible options and the difference is really crusial:

1) That there should be no less than 2 goalkeepers. 3 goalkeepers is possible (3+11). One goalkeeper is forbidden - Team needs at least another one in case that the first get injured.

2) That there should be exactly 2 goalkeepers on the team (2+12). It is forbidden if there are 3 goalkeepers on the team.

I personally think that 1) is correct but I'm not 100% sure to tell you the truth.

Comment: This isn't a question about *shall*. It's a question about *two of whom*.

Comment: Since [section 23.1](http://www.concacaf.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/FIFA-Beach-Soccer-World-Cup-Regulations-2009.pdf) says *"Each Participating Member Association shall submit a provisional list of players (a minimum of two of whom shall be goalkeepers)"* and 23.2 says *"The final team list of the 12 players (two of whom shall be goalkeepers)"*, it presumably means exactly two. Otherwise they would have said *"a minimum of two"*.

Comment: 1) or 2)? What would you choose ?

Comment: In this specific example, it is probably best to define what is meant by 'goalkeeper'. Since, as far as I'm aware, players may swap positions (obviously notifying the officials before they swap the goalkeeper with someone else), does 'two of whom shall be goalkeepers' have any legal meaning?

Comment: "Two" means "two".  It does not mean "2 or more".  When you said "Two possible options", did you mean "Two or more possible options?"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth the FIFA disagrees. [Here](https://www.theguardian.com/football/2010/jun/03/north-korea-world-cup-goalkeeper-gamble). The goalkeepers are the guys with the gloves and only the squad's goal keepers are allowed on that position - barring too many injuries or red cards.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: There are special rules for goalkeepers. For example, only goalkeepers can catch the ball.

Comment: @Helmar Good spot. But they're moving the goalposts.

Comment: @Peter I was watching Man United almost 50 years ago. 'Goalkeeper' was the player most recently designated to be allowed to catch the ball in the penalty area (etc) (and _not_ designated days, weeks, months, years beforehand). Five minutes later, it could be a different person. And on one occasion, my favourite striker donned the gloves when the usual keeper sustained an injury.

Comment: Relevant: ['A / One / At least one student entered the room.' Are these the same? (truth-conditionally)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292760) and all of the linked answers.

Comment: Even if it means you can only have two goalkeepers, it doesn't necessarily mean that substitutions are not possible if one of the original ones gets injured. This question on Sports SE seems relevant,  I don't know if you've seen it: [Football - If you can't change an injured goaltender, what can you do?](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/14511/football-if-you-cant-change-an-injured-goaltender-what-can-you-do)

Answer (score 2):

As this is English Language and Usage:

"two of whom shall be goalkeepers" means that two of them must be goalkeepers. It doesn't, in terms of English grammar, say anything about whether or not the others may be goalkeepers.

---

If you would like to understand how FIFA's rules are applied, I suggest [Sports.SE](https://sports.stackexchange.com/).

If you have a situation where you are being penalised for not meeting a rule which you believe you meet, and you are considering a formal complaint, I suggest [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

While *two of whom shall be goalkeepers* might be ambiguous if it stood alone in a document, the FIFA rules make its meaning clear.

Consider [this document](http://resources.fifa.com/mm/document/tournament/competition/02/73/49/51/ffwccol2016weben_neutral.pdf) (2016 world cup rules).

Section 27.1 says

> Each Participating Member Association shall submit a provisional list of
>   players (a minimum of two of whom shall be goalkeepers)

Section 27.3 says

> The final list of the 14 players (two of whom shall be goalkeepers) selected
>   to participate in the final competition

If the writers of the rules had intended section 27.3 to mean *at least two*, they would have used the same wording as in Section 27.1.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a rule stating that a team can't swap their goalkeeper with another player after say ten minutes. If this is still the case*, what does the FIFA use of 'goalkeeper' actually mean? Test cricket teams can certainly include more than one recognised wicket-keeper (though only one may operate as such at any one time). / *It is: 'a keeper may swap places with any of the outfield player[s] as long as it is done during stoppage time' [[Football Bible.com](http://www.football-bible.com/soccer-info/goalkeeper-rules.html)].

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: The rules also say: *In the event of a goalkeeper needing to be replaced by an out-field player (due to injuries or red cards), each team shall provide a goalkeeper jersey without a number displayed on the back of the shirt in order to distinguish this replacement goalkeeper from the other players.* So presumably you can replace a goalkeeper with another player (and vice versa) only in the event of injuries and/or penalties.

Comment: Which rules? There seem to be different and conflicting lists available. Some may be out-of-date; some may apply only to specified competitions.

Comment: Actually, you're right ... those were the wrong set of rules.

Comment: Is any of this relevant, or is this descending into something more suited to Law.SE? About the only relevant thing I can see to *English Language and Usage* is the implication that the language of the clause is ambiguous.

Comment: @AndyT The relevance is that it's pointless trying to sort out whether the string 'two of whom shall be goalkeepers' is ambiguous or not when the term 'goalkeeper' is itself nowadays inherently ambiguous (see Phil Sweet's answer, which should really be a 'comment').

Answer (score 0):

"shall" means "must" here, or more precisely "must, according to the rules,".

The use of "shall" to mean "must" is common in regulatory documents:  the tone of the document is that they describe a *hypothetical situation in which everyone follows the rules*.

Similarly the word "will" is often used to describe aspects which are not dependent on the "players", or the people **following** the rules.  It's like a covenant in which the organisers **will** do some things (eg set up the tournament) and the players **shall** (choose to) follow the rules.

Here's a document talking about this from the American Nuclear Society (ANS), in which they set out the rules for the use of "shall", "should" and "may".

http://cdn.ans.org/standards/resources/toolkit/docs/policy-specifying-req-rec-perm-standard.pdf

Comment: ANS uses the rules often used in American legal documents, and FIFA is an international organization.

Comment: Do you agree with Peter Shor that 2) is correct? That there must not be 3 goalkeepers on the list.

Comment: @PeterShor I just included the ANS doc as an example of the sort of rules that exist around words like "shall" in regulations.  I didn't mean to imply that those rules were binding for all regulations, everywhere, relating to all things.  I couldn't find a similar document for FIFA.

Comment: @Neitrino I don't actually know:  I was just saying that it's the same as saying "2 of whom must be goalkeepers".  I think it's quite ambiguous.  Which means that my answer doesn't actually answer the question.  FWIW I'd guess that it means "There must be exactly two goalkeepers".

Comment: I don't see how it can mean anything except "exactly two goalkeepers".

Comment: @DavidGarner I'm confident that if either of us could be bothered we could find examples of people using this sort of language to describe the requirement for a minimum number, rather than an exact amount, whether or not that's the case in this specific example.

Comment: But person who asked this topic on my russian forum insist that number of teams that submit (2+12) and teams (3+11) is about 50%/50% sometimes. I am not a fan so I don't know for sure. And there were serious disagreenment - if 2) is right why they submit (3+1).

Comment: @Neitrino if you want to know what the language means, I think it's been answered as good as you're going to get.  If you want some clarification about **the actual rules** then you should ask FIFA, or ask on a Beach Soccer forum or something.  Ultimately, if you turn up with the wrong number of goalkeepers, it doesn't matter what we think about the wording of the rules.

Comment: Max Williams, I only wanted to find out what natives think about that phrase. Because this modal Shall is very rare really and I can't really recall when I met it last time in popular books like The Magisians, Harry Potter and so on (which I reads on purpose of studying English). The only example I do remember is - "You shall be his wife" says a tsar to his daugther - :-)

Comment: The modal *shall* is very common in legal-like documents, where it means *must*, as in this answer.

Comment: On reflection, and after talking with a colleague, I'm not so sure, and would accept that without the word 'exactly' it could mean 'at least two goalkeepers'.

Comment: Interpreting "shall" to mean "must" doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that "two must be goalkeepers" does not say that "the other twelve must not be goalkeepers." In normal English, this is the implication, but it's not actually *logically* implied (see this question and other linked questions: ['A / One / At least one student entered the room.' Are these the same? (truth-conditionally)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292760))

Comment: Here is two examples which show this topic and misunderstanding:  1)[link](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/footballdevelopment/technicalsupport/02/01/25/77/futsalwmthawebversion2.pdf) pade 136 - Australia 3 GK  2) [link](http://www.fifa.com/futsalworldcup/archive/thailand2012/teams/team=1883208/players.html) - 3GK

Comment: I agree with @PeterShor.  I've just ridden an escalator in a Liverpool underground station, and read a sign saying, "Small children shall be held firmly."

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be confusion between the attributes of the local label "goalkeeper", which pertains throughout the document, and the global label "goalkeeper", which pertains outside the document. Just change every instance of "goalkeeper" in the document to "poodle". If you need to coordinate goalkeeper with poodle, then **spell out exactly how in the front of the doc**. After a time, you just automatically start to drop the global labels when you read these kinds of governance documents.

> When I use a word,” Humpty Dumpty said, in rather a scornful tone, “it
>   means just what I choose it to mean—neither more nor less.” “The
>   question is,” said Alice, “whether you can make words mean so many
>   different things.” “The question is,” said Humpty Dumpty, “which is to
>   be master—that's all.

We know which is to be master. From  LEWIS CARROLL (Charles L. Dodgson), Through the Looking-Glass, chapter 6, p. 205 (1934). First published in 1872.

Maybe an edit will appease the downvoter. What it means is that all future references to "goalkeeper" in the document refer to the two persons declared to be goalkeepers in the final list.

Comment: This is indeed a problem with the example chosen. As has been pointed out.